# How to remove permanent login and password entry in git?

Tags: git, github

I work in a private git repository, I encountered this problem: every time when I go outside the local repository, you need to enter the login and password for the GitHub account (e.g during push, clone, pull).

How can I remove this input or make git remember my data and not ask me to enter it every time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take a look to that:

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential-store

Or add your private SSH KEY on your git account